# Bing Ads Problems with desktop auth

Tags: java, oauth, desktop, ads, bing-api

I have used this sample Bing Ads application for auth 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-java-walkthrough-desktop-application.aspx

But there are some issues with it. I can login only using the account that has the specified ClientId and DeveloperToken. When I tried to login using another account I got AdApiError: 105, InvalidCredentials or account inactive. 
Does anyone know what trouble is here? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft account that you use to login must have access to at least one Bing Ads account. It is possible that you used a valid Microsoft account user who does not have access to any Bing Ads accounts. If you are able to login to Bing Ads web application with that user, and still observing a 105 error when calling the Bing Ads API, then I suggest that you [contact support](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/bing-ads-support) for a closer look. I hope this helps!